# GPU + CPU rendering (2.80)

Tags: rendering

Is there a way to concentrate all the CPU power into one single tile, via settings? And ideally the CPU would be used at %100.

While rendering CPU + GPU, I noticed the CPU slows down the render using the default automatic tiles and threads(12) settings. (I've got 3 GPUs)

Many thanks.

Comment: Might be faster just using the GPUs with a large tile size then, if the overhead with GPU + CPU is too large.

Comment: It seems in majority of cases it is faster to use small tile sizes and render with GPU and CPU. It is different in 2.80 than what we are all used to with tile sizes. Small tile sizes work a lot better with GPUs in 2.80. At least when I tested a few months back.

Comment: @MartinZ You're right, might even be a little faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could choose to use 1 thread, but that is a **really bad idea**. It will render slower and will not use the CPU to its full potential.

Try to optimize the tile size instead. Try small sizes like 16x16 as well. Don't worry about the GPU - GPU rendering is a lot more optimized for small tile sizes in 2.80.

[image]

See what uses the CPU most efficiently and renders fastest. You cannot use multiple CPU cores on one tile efficiently.